# Cobalt2 Theme VSCode Blue Colors

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Sorry for the dumb question, but can someone please help me with the below (I've tried everything at this point and am going crazy). I am using the official WesBos Cobalt2 theme https://github.com/wesbos/cobalt2-vscode/blob/master/theme/cobalt2.json

However recently most of the colors got with this really annoying blue: #9effff

I can't seem to find a way to change it no matter what I try and it is really annoying.

Here is a screenshot of test snippet:

[image]

My settings are as follow:

````
  "editor.fontFamily": "Operator Mono, Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",
  "editor.fontSize": 15,
  "editor.lineHeight": 25,
  "editor.letterSpacing": 0.5,
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
  "editor.fontWeight": "400",
  "editor.cursorStyle": "line",
  "editor.cursorWidth": 5,
  "editor.cursorBlinking": "solid",
  "vscode_custom_css.imports": [
    "file:///pathtofile.scss"
  ],
  "vscode_custom_css.policy": true,
  "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
  "files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
  "sync.gist": "",
  "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    {
      "language": "typescript",
      "autoFix": true
    },
    {
      "language": "typescriptreact",
      "autoFix": true
    }
  ],
  "eslint.options": {
    "extensions": [
      ".js",
      ".jsx",
      ".ts",
      ".tsx"
    ]
  },
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib",
  "stylelint.enable": true,
  "prettier.ignorePath": "",
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can change the syntax highlight colors by using the `"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {}` setting.

Here's a head start:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Cobalt2]": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "name": "Comment",
                "scope": [
                    "comment",
                    "punctuation.definition.comment"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "italic",
                    "foreground": "#0088ff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "HTML Tags",
                "scope": "entity.name.tag",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#9EFFFF"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[HTML] - Quotes. these are a slightly different colour because expand selection will then not include quotes",
                "scope": "punctuation.definition.string.begin, punctuation.definition.string.end",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#3ad900"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "String",
                "scope": [
                    "string",
                    "punctuation.definition.string"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#3ad900"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "String Template",
                "scope": [
                    "string.template",
                    "punctuation.definition.string.template"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#3ad900"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[CSS] - Entity",
                "scope": [
                    "source.css entity",
                    "source.stylus entity"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#3ad900"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[CSS] - ID Selector",
                "scope": "entity.other.attribute-name.id.css",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#3ad900"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[CSS] - Support",
                "scope": [
                    "source.css support",
                    "source.stylus support"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffc600"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[CSS] - Constant",
                "scope": [
                    "source.css constant",
                    "source.css support.constant",
                    "source.stylus constant",
                    "source.stylus support.constant"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ff628c"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Assignment",
                "scope": [
                    "punctuation.separator",
                    "keyword.operator.assignment"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#3ad900"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Constant",
                "scope": "constant",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ff628c"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Entity",
                "scope": "entity",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffc600"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Invalid",
                "scope": "invalid",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#f44542"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Storage Type Function",
                "scope": "storage.type.function",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ff9d00"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Keyword",
                "scope": "keyword, storage.type.class",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ff9d00"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Meta",
                "scope": "meta",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#9effff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Meta JSX",
                "scope": [
                    "meta.jsx.children",
                    "meta.jsx.children.js",
                    "meta.jsx.children.tsx"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#fff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Meta Brace",
                "scope": "meta.brace",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#e1efff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Punctuation",
                "scope": "punctuation.terminator",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffffff66"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Punctuation Parameters",
                "scope": "punctuation.definition.parameters",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffee80"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Punctuation Template Expression",
                "scope": "punctuation.definition.template-expression",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffee80"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Storage",
                "scope": "storage",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffc600"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Storage Type Arrow Function",
                "scope": "storage.type.function.arrow",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffc600"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Support",
                "scope": "support",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#80ffbb"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Support Function",
                "scope": "support.function",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ff9d00"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Support Variable Property DOM",
                "scope": "support.variable.property.dom",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#e1efff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Variable",
                "scope": "variable",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#e1efff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[CSS] - String",
                "scope": [
                    "source.css string",
                    "source.css punctuation.definition.string",
                    "source.stylus string",
                    "source.stylus punctuation.definition.string"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffee80"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[CSS] - Variable",
                "scope": [
                    "source.css variable",
                    "source.stylus variable"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#9effff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[HTML] - Entity Name",
                "scope": "text.html.basic entity.name",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#9effff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[HTML] - ID value",
                "scope": "meta.toc-list.id.html",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#A5FF90"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[HTML] - Entity Other",
                "scope": "text.html.basic entity.other",
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "italic",
                    "foreground": "#ffc600"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[HTML] - Script Tag",
                "scope": "meta.tag.metadata.script.html entity.name.tag.html",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffc600"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[INI] - Entity",
                "scope": "source.ini entity",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#e1efff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[INI] - Keyword",
                "scope": "source.ini keyword",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffc600"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[INI] - Punctuation Definition",
                "scope": "source.ini punctuation.definition",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffee80"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[INI] - Punctuation Separator",
                "scope": "source.ini punctuation.separator",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ff9d00"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[JAVASCRIPT] - Storage Type Function",
                "scope": "source.js storage.type.function",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#fb94ff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[JAVASCRIPT] - Variable Language",
                "scope": "variable.language, entity.name.type.class.js",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#fb94ff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[JAVASCRIPT] - Inherited Component",
                "scope": "entity.other.inherited-class.js",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ccc"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[PYTHON] - Self Argument",
                "scope": "variable.parameter.function.language.special.self.python",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#fb94ff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[JSON] - Support",
                "scope": "source.json support",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffc600"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[JSON] - String",
                "scope": [
                    "source.json string",
                    "source.json punctuation.definition.string"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#e1efff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[MARKDOWN] - Heading Punctuation",
                "scope": "punctuation.definition.heading.markdown",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#e1efff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[MARKDOWN] - Heading Name Section",
                "scope": [
                    "entity.name.section.markdown",
                    "markup.heading.setext.1.markdown",
                    "markup.heading.setext.2.markdown"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "bold",
                    "foreground": "#ffc600"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[MARKDOWN] - Paragraph",
                "scope": "meta.paragraph.markdown",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#e1efff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[MARKDOWN] - Quote Punctuation",
                "scope": "beginning.punctuation.definition.quote.markdown",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffc600"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[MARKDOWN] - Quote Paragraph",
                "scope": "markup.quote.markdown meta.paragraph.markdown",
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "italic",
                    "foreground": "#9effff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[MARKDOWN] - Separator",
                "scope": "meta.separator.markdown",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffc600"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[MARKDOWN] - Emphasis Bold",
                "scope": "markup.bold.markdown",
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "bold",
                    "foreground": "#9effff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[MARKDOWN] - Emphasis Italic",
                "scope": "markup.italic.markdown",
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "italic",
                    "foreground": "#9effff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[MARKDOWN] - Lists",
                "scope": "beginning.punctuation.definition.list.markdown",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffc600"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[MARKDOWN] - Link Title",
                "scope": "string.other.link.title.markdown",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#a5ff90"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[MARKDOWN] - Link/Image Title",
                "scope": [
                    "string.other.link.title.markdown",
                    "string.other.link.description.markdown",
                    "string.other.link.description.title.markdown"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#a5ff90"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[MARKDOWN] - Link Address",
                "scope": [
                    "markup.underline.link.markdown",
                    "markup.underline.link.image.markdown"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#9effff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[MARKDOWN] - Inline Code",
                "scope": [
                    "fenced_code.block.language",
                    "markup.inline.raw.markdown"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#9effff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[MARKDOWN] - Code Block",
                "scope": [
                    "fenced_code.block.language",
                    "markup.inline.raw.markdown"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#9effff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[PUG] - Entity Name",
                "scope": "text.jade entity.name",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#9effff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[PUG] - Entity Attribute Name",
                "scope": "text.jade entity.other.attribute-name.tag",
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "italic"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[PUG] - String Interpolated",
                "scope": "text.jade string.interpolated",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffee80"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[TYPESCRIPT] - Entity Name Type",
                "scope": "source.ts entity.name.type",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#80ffbb"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[TYPESCRIPT] - Keyword",
                "scope": "source.ts keyword",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffc600"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[TYPESCRIPT] - Punctuation Parameters",
                "scope": "source.ts punctuation.definition.parameters",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#e1efff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[TYPESCRIPT] - Punctuation Arrow Parameters",
                "scope": "meta.arrow.ts punctuation.definition.parameters",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffee80"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[TYPESCRIPT] - Storage",
                "scope": "source.ts storage",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#9effff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[TYPESCRIPT] - Variable Language",
                "scope": "variable.language, entity.name.type.class.ts, entity.name.type.class.tsx",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#fb94ff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[TYPESCRIPT] - Inherited Component",
                "scope": "entity.other.inherited-class.ts, entity.other.inherited-class.tsx",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ccc"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[PHP] - Entity",
                "scope": "source.php entity",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#9effff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[PHP] - Variables",
                "scope": "variable.other.php",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffc600"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[C#] - Annotations",
                "scope": "storage.type.cs",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#9effff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[C#] - Properties",
                "scope": "entity.name.variable.property.cs",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#9effff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[C#] - Storage modifiers",
                "scope": "storage.modifier.cs",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#80ffbb"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Italicsify for Operator Mono",
                "scope": [
                    "modifier",
                    "this",
                    "comment",
                    "storage.modifier.js",
                    "storage.modifier.ts",
                    "storage.modifier.tsx",
                    "entity.other.attribute-name.js",
                    "entity.other.attribute-name.ts",
                    "entity.other.attribute-name.tsx",
                    "entity.other.attribute-name.html"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "italic"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[CSHARP] - Modifiers and keyword types",
                "scope": "storage.modifier.cs, keyword.type.cs",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#fb94ff"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[CSHARP] - Storage types",
                "scope": "storage.type.cs",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#80ffbb"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[CSHARP] - Namespaces, parameters, field variables, properties",
                "scope": "entity.name.type.namespace.cs, entity.name.variable.parameter.cs, entity.name.variable.field.cs, entity.name.variable.property.cs",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#e1efff"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: thank you! I found out that the problem is only in the return statement jsx. Any idea what to change there to make the foreground font normal?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the syntax highlighting inside the return statement in JSX is coming from the HTML syntax highlighting, so if you change HTML's syntax highlighting, you change the syntax highlighting inside the return statement. Let me know if it works.